# How to inject webapi AccountController in WebApi

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-web-api2

I have default constuctor and constructor with params like here:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> AccessTokenFormat { get; private set; }
    [Dependency]
    public IRepository Repository{ get; private set; }

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
    }
}
```

And my unity config here:

```
.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>, ApplicationUserManager>()                
.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>()

.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>()
.RegisterType<ITextEncoder, Base64UrlTextEncoder>()
.RegisterType<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>, TicketSerializer>()
//.RegisterType<IDataProtector>(() => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity"))

.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, CustomUserStore>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)))
.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication))
.RegisterType<IOwinContext>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()))
.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>();
```

But the thing is that default constructor is always getting called.
I read taht article [blog](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/) but they not talking how to resolve such case with constructor havaving params `AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)`

If I am taking off parameterless constructor I am getting an error: `"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",`
Is there anyone can help?

Also I have just normal ApiController and i is not getting injected as well:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Dependency]
    public IRepository Repository { get; set; }

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var test = Repository.GetSomething(); // Repository is null here always
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1** Based on @IgorPashchuk suggeston now `MyController` is getting injected now.
But AccoutController is not. I am removed the default constructor but still getting the error.

**UPDATE 2** I alter the constructor with params by taking out the second param:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    [Dependency]
    public IRepository Repository{ get; private set; }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

So this way I've got the thing is working. Is I understand that is means that Unity wasnt able to construct type `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>`. I post another question about this issue [How to construct ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> with unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445571/how-to-construct-isecuredataformatauthenticationticket-with-unity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the parameterless constructor.

Next, you need to configure a custom dependency resolver, which will basically wrap your Unity container.  See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

After that, make sure that you register all your types.  For example, I don't see a registration for `ApplicationUserManager`.  You are registering `UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>` but not `ApplicationUserManager`, which is what the IoC container will attempt to resolve.

Comment: `ApplicationUserManager` is there: `.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>()`

Comment: Do i need `Unity.Mvc` package still? It is seams like I do not need that any more?

Comment: @sreginogemoh, you are right.  Sorry, I missed that.  The answer to your second question is: it depends.  You don't need it for this purpose.  But, you definitely need to create a custom dependency resolver because Web API does not know about your Unity container otherwise.