# How to construct ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> with unity

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-web-api2

I have consturctor on my webapi account controller looking like that:

```
public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
{
   _userManager = userManager;
   AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
}
```

But Unity is not able to consruct the `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>`because the constructor is not working untill I taking off the second param.

```
public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
{
   _userManager = userManager;
}
```

How I can construct the second param with Unity?
My Unityconfig:

```
.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>, ApplicationUserManager>()                
.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>()

.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>()
.RegisterType<ITextEncoder, Base64UrlTextEncoder>()
.RegisterType<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>, TicketSerializer>()
//.RegisterType<IDataProtector>(() => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity"))

.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, CustomUserStore>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)))
.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication))
.RegisterType<IOwinContext>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()))
.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>();
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @Barks in case of constructor with two params I am getting an error `An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type "AccountController". Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.` For my understanding in such case Unity cant constract that and falling to default constructor but I do not have default one and this way I am getting that error. So by taking off the `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` I find out that there is an issue with it because this way I do not have any issues with `ApplicationUserManager ` when it is just a single param.

Comment: does AccountController has parameterless public constructor? if not - add it

Comment: @Barks If I add it is always gonna be called and my dependency injecton won't work. Here is related question I asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444534/how-to-inject-webapi-accountcontroller-in-webapi/32444659#32444659

Comment: Why isn't `ApplicationUserManager` registered with Unity?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't registered type `IDataProvider` within `UnityContainer` 
(I don't knows why you comment out that within your unity config) however `SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` constructor requires that.

```
public class SecureDataFormat<TData> : ISecureDataFormat<TData>
{
    public SecureDataFormat(IDataSerializer<TData> serializer, IDataProtector protector, ITextEncoder encoder)
```

I was also facing the same issue. Following unity config resolved issue for me

```
container.RegisterType<ITextEncoder, Base64UrlTextEncoder>();
container.RegisterType<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>, TicketSerializer>();
container.RegisterInstance(new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
container.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>();
```

Comment: Can you advise where **SecureDataFormat** is located?