# How to configure Unity container for AccountController in identity authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, unity-container

My controller is like :

```cs
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
        ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat,
        ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
        _roleManager = roleManager;

    }
}
```

In UnityConfig.cs I try to configure like this way :

```cs
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
        // container.LoadConfiguration();

        // TODO: Register your types here
        container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        container.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>();
    }
```

In WebApiConfig.cs :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(container);
        //Set the unity container as the default dependency resolver
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

And in Global.asax.cs :

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); // At the beginning, register with HttpConfiguration
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

But when i try to retrieve role using roleManager (`var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(model.RoleId);`) it says :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I see there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32444534/3835843), but it can't solve my problem.

Comment: Which is null? `_roleManager` or `model`? That is possibility given the objects involved. You need to debug and see which it is

Comment: @Nkosi `model.RoleId` is getting 3 and `_roleManager` inject when controller initialize. That is not problem, but here i am sure something wrong  in my UnityConfig.

Comment: Why do you have the parametrless constructor?

Comment: @Nkosi Actually i don't do anything in this  AccountController, it creates automatically when i create a new **Web API** project with authentication in visual studio.

Comment: Understood, but it should be removed.

Comment: @Nkosi Removed, but then it doesn't initialize the controller.

Comment: Then that mean that your DI/Dependency resolver is not performing as expected. It was using the default constructor and not initializing the managers. Show the Unity setup in a [mcve]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151159/discussion-between-arif-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 1):

Based on how the code in the question looks I believe you are using Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET Web API which should wire up a `UnityDependencyResolver`.

```
container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

This registers the AccountController and instructs Unity to use the paramterless constructor.  This is why all of your dependencies are null.  If you want to use the other constructor remove the `AccountController` registration and Unity will use the constructor with the most parameters.  However if you do this then you will get a runtime error attempting to resolve the `AccountController` because `ISecureDataFormat<>` is not registered and Unity will not know how to map that interface to a concrete type.

If you register a mapping to `SecureDataFormat<>` then there are some additional dependencies that will need to be registered.

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ISecureDataFormat<>), typeof(SecureDataFormat<>));
container.RegisterType<ITextEncoder, Base64UrlTextEncoder>()
container.RegisterType<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>, TicketSerializer>()        
container.RegisterType<IDataProtector>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(c => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("App Name")));
```

Note that the above registrations are not tested.  Not sure if you should configure OWIN with data protection (and perhaps get the protection provider from the OWIN config).

The following two registrations are not strictly required since Unity knows how to resolve a concrete type without a registration and no additional `InjectionMembers` are being provided (e.g. lifetime, parameters overrides etc.).

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
container.RegisterType<ApplicationRoleManager>();
```